# Can I get a public variable from a web service?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have a web service I'm using to collect some information from a DB. Just a few strings mostly. However, instead of returning in my function. I wanted to make a get function that I could call later. However, after putting in some break points, it seems that the variables I stored become null once the call returns from the service function that had just pulled them from the DB, to my main project.

Obviously I'm unsure how web service's really work. Is there a special way to do this like setting a session variable?

thanks

```
 [WebMethod]
    public String getDemogs()
    {
        return Demogs;
    }



    [WebMethod]
    public void LoadUserSites(string username, string siteUse)
    {
        // Declare the SslConnection class variable.
        SqlConnection sSitesConn = new SqlConnection(Util.ConStrEpcrProd);
        SqlCommand sSitesCmd = new SqlCommand();
        sSitesCmd.Connection = sSitesConn;
        SqlDataReader objSitesReader;

        try
        {
            sSitesConn.Open();

            if (siteUse == "Main")
            {
                sSitesCmd.CommandText = "SELECT AgencyName, Demog FROM dbo.UserAdminPermissions WHERE UserName = '" + username + "'";

                objSitesReader = sSitesCmd.ExecuteReader();

                // Reset the string...
                Demogs = string.Empty;
                Agencies = string.Empty;

                while (objSitesReader.Read())
                {
                    Demogs += objSitesReader["Demog"].ToString() + ",";
                    Agencies += "'" + objSitesReader["AgencyName"].ToString() + "',";
                }



                objSitesReader.Close();
                objSitesReader.Dispose();
            }


        finally
        {
            sSitesConn.Close();
            sSitesConn.Dispose();
            sSitesCmd.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show us some code, none here can help without it. Also, what kind of web service? asmx? wcf?

Answer (score 0):

`Demogs` is not available between calls if you store it in a class variable. You need to store it elsewhere (session, wherever). You will always get a new instance of your service class on each call to the service.

Comment: ah, ok. So can I do something like session["demogs"] = demogs in my web service?

Comment: You can, yes. If this is what you want. And, then, return that one in `getDemoGs`. But, if you really need sessions, and this is what you want, you need to decide for yourself. If you don't want to use sessions, you can of course return a "query ID" from the first (load) method, then use that one to look up in the second (get) method.